# Is there a way to render a js.erb after a fetch call?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fetch, erb

In my Rails app, I want to render a js.erb partial after a fetch call and for some reasons I do not understand it does not work. If you can help me, it would be great.

In a view, an event trigger this function that basically do a fetch request:

```
function updateState(id, state){
      const csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attributes
          .content.value;
      fetch(window.location.origin + "/update_state", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            'Accept': "JS",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({'id': id, 'state': state}),
          credentials: "same-origin"
        })
}
```

Then in my controller:

```
  def update_state
    @model = Model.find(params[:id])
    authorize @model
    @model.update(state: params[:state])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to xxx }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

In my js.erb files:

```
console.log('hello');
```

However, in that case, I get an error from the server:
ActionController::UnknownFormat
at the line 'respond_to do |format|
I have the feeling that the server do not understand the header of the fetch:
'Accept': "JS"

When I look at the logs of the server:

```
Started POST "/update_state" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-04-04 11:22:49 +0200
Processing by ModelsController#update_state as JS
```

But I think that Rails does not recognize it. How do I do?

I tried also this in the controller:

```
  def update_state
    @model = Model.find(params[:id])
    authorize @model
    @model.update(state: params[:state])
    render 'update_state.js', layout: false
  end
```

Which does not fire errors. I received in the client side the js.erb. However, it is not executed (console.log does not execute).

Do you have any idea? Thank a lot for your help.

Comment: Comment out the `header` section and see what happens.

Comment: I can't remove the header. Otherwise, it raises an error:
- Removal of Accept --> will redirect directly to the html (format.html)
- Removal of the Content-type --> will not recognize the body of the fetch
- Removal of the X-CSRF-Token --> will raise a ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage the other way around. I never succeded with js.erb.

So I use a fetch call with a response in text:

```
function updateState(id, state){
  const csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attributes
      .content.value;
  fetch(window.location.origin + "/update_state", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': "JS",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({'id': id, 'state': state}),
      credentials: "same-origin"
    }).then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => {
       div.inserAdjacentHTML('XXX', data);
    });
}
```

Then in the controller/action:

```
  def update_state
    @model = Model.find(params[:id])
    authorize @model
    @model.update(state: params[:state])
    render 'update_state.js', layout: false, content_type: "text/plain"
  end
```

That way, it works. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit : look at the edit for a fully working solution on triggering manually a .js.erb file.*

Had the same issue and there are actually two problems here. Your are right, your headers are not. These headers to trigger the `.js.erb` worked for me and seems pretty right :

```
'dataType': 'json',
'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
'X-CSRF-Token': - your CSRF method to get the token -
```

But secondly to trigger the js response, your `respond_to` block :

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to xxx }
  format.js
end
```

Has to have the format.js first. As rails has a response for the HTML it will respond with HTML first and seems to not even look for the next format block.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.html { redirect_to xxx }
end
```

Hope it helps :-)

### **Edit 13/11/2018**

Hey, long time no see ! The same issue happened to me again and my own previous reply wasn't solving the issue. Like you, the .js.erb file was rendered but nothing happened and the `console.log` was not displayed. So I created a `link_to` with `remote: true` that triggered my `.js.erb` file and compared the requests. Everything was the same except one thing : the type of the request. One was a fetch, the other was an `xhr`. It appears that the `.js.erb` files are triggered only by the `xhr` requests. So the solution is to build an old `xhr` request instead of a fetch, like this :

```
    const url = 'your_custom_path' // Build the url to fetch
    const csrf = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Will be a GET request here
    xhr.open('GET', url, false);
​    
    // Setting the headers
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('dataType', 'script');
​
    // What to do with the response
    xhr.onload = function() {
      let responseObj = xhr.response
      eval(responseObj) // You need to eval() manually the response for it to be executed
    }
​
    // Sending the request
    xhr.send()
```

Hope it helps, even some months later! ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However it does not work completly. Indeed, when changing the headers & switching the format lines, I do not get any errors. However, I come back to the other option of my question: I received in the client side the js.erb. However, it is not executed (console.log does not execute).

Do you have any other idea? I really do not understand.

Comment: Hey ! Found to solution to your issue. Should be working now. Exactly 6 month day for day :)

Comment: Understood! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue in Rails 6 using fetch.  My issue was solved by simply placing format.js above format.html.  Thanks @holino.  The following fetch works.

```
  fetch(event.currentTarget.dataset.destroyPath, {
    method: 'DELETE',
    dataType: 'script',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': csrf
    },
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using `Rails.ajax`, like the below:

```js
Rails.ajax({
  url: `/endpoint`,
  type: "get",
  data: new URLSearchParams({parameter_a: "data"}).toString(),
  accept: 'js',
  dataType: 'script',
  success: function(data) {},
  error: function(data) {}
})
```

If you try and use `fetch`, you will run into issues as you will need to execute the javascript returned from the server. When you use remote: true, rails-ujs will actually insert a script tag with the JS script you return in your view so it gets executed (and then it removes it):

```js
# if it's a script, attach it to the DOM
script = document.createElement('script')
script.setAttribute('nonce', cspNonce())
script.text = response
document.head.appendChild(script).parentNode.removeChild(script)
```

If you use `Rails.ajax`, this problem will be solved.